# Is there a way to set SelectedIndex of a ComboBox inside a MahApps.Metro Flyout?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I have a `UserControl` that is contained in a `MahApps.Metro.Controls.Flyout`.  Inside that `UserControl`, there is a `ComboBox`.  I'm trying to set the default `SelectedIndex` to 0.    So that when the flyout is opened, the first item ("Source A") is selected.

Currently, whenever the flyout is opened, the `SelectedIndex` is being set to -1 and nothing is selected.

**View that holds the Flyout:**

```
<mah:FlyoutsControl>
    <mah:Flyout IsOpen="{Binding MyViewIsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    x:Name="DataSourceFlyout">
        <Grid>
            <local:DataSourceView/>
        </Grid>
    </mah:Flyout>
</mah:FlyoutsControl>
```

**DataSourceView:**

```
<UserControl ...>
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" 
      SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDataSource, Mode=TwoWay, 
      UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
      SynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="SourceA" Content="Source A"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="SourceB" Content="Source B"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Tag="SourceC" Content="Source C"/>
    </ComboBox>
</UserControl>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public string SelectedDataSource { get; set; }
```

**Note:** This seems to be caused by my `UserControl` being within a `Flyout`.   The same XAML works fine when used outside of a `Flyout`.  Is there something else I need to do to get the first item selected in my `ComboBox`?

Comment: "*This seems to be caused by my UserControl being within a Flyout*" So where is the `Flyout` in your sample markup...?

Comment: @mm8 I left that code out in an attempt to keep the sample markup as simple as possible.  But you are right, maybe it has something to do with my issue.  I've added the `Flyout` XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source property in the view model determines the value to be selected.

It's unclear what the value of the `SelectedDataSource` property is in your example but you should set it to either "SourceA", "SourceB" or "SourceC" and then set the `SelectedValuePath` property to "Tag":

```
<ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDataSource, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedValuePath="Tag">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="SourceA" Content="Source A"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="SourceB" Content="Source B"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="SourceC" Content="Source C"/>
</ComboBox>
```

**View Model:**

```
public string SelectedDataSource { get; set; } = "SourceA";
```

If you intend to specify the selected value in the view using the `SelectedIndex` property, you should remove the binding.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly this did not work either.  When the Flyout is opened, the SelectedIndex is still being set to -1.  I've found a temporary, albeit ugly, solution.  When the SelectionChanged event occurs, I check to see if the new SelectedIndex is -1.  If it is, I set it the index to 0.   I'd still like to try and find a solution that doesn't rely on the code-behind file.

Comment: @KyleWilliamson: Hmm...this does work for me.